# Upper bound for an expression involving an integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a function such that $|f(u)-f(v)| \leq |u-v|$ for all $u$ and $v$ in the interval $[a,b]$.
>
> Prove that
> $$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx- (b-a)f(c)\right| \leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}$$
> where $c\in [a,b]$.

Is f continuous?

Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What is $c$? What did you try?

Comment: I suppose $c\in [a,b]$, no ? By the way, what is the connection between the question and the title ?

Comment: What has the question to do with the title?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$f(c)(b-a)=\int_a^b f(c)dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

As @Surd suggests, we have

\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx - f(c)(b-a)\right| &= \left|\int_a^b f(x)\,dx - \int_a^b f(c)\,dx\right|\\
&= \left|\int_a^b (f(x) - f(c))\,dx\right|\\
&\le \int_a^b |f(x) - f(c)|\,dx\\
&\le \int_a^b |x-c|\,dx\\
&= \int_a^c(c-x)\,dx + \int_c^b (x-c)\,dx\\
&= \frac12(c-a)^2 + \frac12(b-c)^2\\
&\le \frac12(b-a)^2 
\end{align}

because

$$(c-a)^2 + (b-c)^2 \le (c-a)^2 + (b-c)^2 + \underbrace{2(c-a)(b-c)}_{\ge0} = \big((c-a) + (b-c)\big)^2 = (b-a)^2$$

Comment: You could also differentiate $c\to\frac12(c-a)^2 + \frac12(b-c)^2$ to find the minimum is when $c$ is the midpoint (which is pleasing intuitively). Thus the max occurs at an endpoint.

Comment: @zhw Yes, the minimum value also follows from AM-QM: $$\sqrt{\frac{(c-a)^2+(b-c)^2}2} \ge \frac{(c-a) + (b-c)}2 = \frac{b-a}2$$
with equality iff $c = \frac{a+b}2$. I'm not sure how this implies anything about maxima.

Comment: @pabodu No, the minimum of the function $c\mapsto\frac12(c-a)^2 + \frac12(b-c)^2$ is $\frac{(b-a)^2}4$ and it is attained for $c = \frac{a+b}2$. The maximum is $\frac{(b-a)^2}2$ and it is attained for $c = a, b$.

Comment: Is f continuous

Comment: @blueboy Yes it is. For $\varepsilon > 0$ set $\delta = \varepsilon$. We have $$|x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| \le |x-y| < \delta = \varepsilon$$
for all $x,y \in [a,b]$.